# <br> inserted in contenteditable span fails to move cursor

Tags: javascript, firefox, contenteditable

I want all text and breaks to be in spans, which the following code does.  Works perfectly in IE11 and chrome but has a serious issue in FF.  To wit, if the first key entered is < enter >, the cursor fails to move to after the inserted < br >.  The caret position seems to move as the next key entered is on the next line but the flashing cursor doesn't.  Furthermore, if backspaced to remove the character, the cursor goes back up to the first line.

Easiest way to demonstrate :http://jsfiddle.net/jd2d7n3L/20/

1. Make the first character entered < enter >
2. Expected result (which is what happens in chrome and IE10+) is for the flashing cursor to move down one line.
3. Enter 'a' and then backspace. Expected result is flashing cursor is leftmost on 2nd line

I have read many similar questions and answers relating to this on SO but none specifically deal with this situation.  How can I make FF behave?

**HTML**

```
<div id=bE contenteditable="true"><br></div>
```

**JS**

```
bE.addEventListener("keypress",KP);
bE.addEventListener("keypress",KU);

function getContainer()
  {
  var eC=window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).endContainer;
  while(eC&&eC.nodeType==3)eC=eC.parentNode;
  return eC
  }

function insertElement(E)
  {
  var sel=window.getSelection(),range=sel.getRangeAt(0);
  range.deleteContents(); 
  range.collapse(true);
  range.insertNode(E);
  range.setStartAfter(E);
  range.collapse(true);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);     
  }

function KP(e)
  {
  var kc=e.which||e.keyCode;
  if(e.charCode||e.which===13)
    {
    var sel=window.getSelection(),range=sel.getRangeAt(0);
    var eC=getContainer();
    if(eC===bE)
      {
      eC=document.createElement("span");
      range.insertNode(eC);
      range.selectNodeContents(eC);
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(range);
      }
    if(kc===13)insertElement(document.createElement("br"));
    else       insertElement(document.createTextNode(String.fromCharCode(kc)));

    e.preventDefault();
    }
  }

function KU(e) //ensures last element is br
  {
  if(!bE.lastChild||bE.lastChild.nodeName.toLowerCase()!=="br")bE.appendChild(document.createElement("br"))
  }
```

Comment: Can you give your functions and variables more meaningful names?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.. "KP" -> keypress, "KU" -> keyup "kc"-> keycode, getContainer, insertElement... self explanatory. Ok "bE" isn't obvious from the name but considering the methods used, it should be obvious it's a div and there is only one div in the html

Comment: How about `document.execCommand("InsertText", false, "\n")`? Won't work in IE but you already have a working solution for IE 10+.

Comment: Just tried it and same problem still occuring.  The issue in FF seems to be that it requires something to come after the br or \n before it moves the caret. If I put a zero width character after br, it works but I really dont want to do that as it makes the rest of the project problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I finally nailed it.  It seems Firefox doesn't like having < br > as the last childnode of any parent.  If you append an empty textnode to every trailing < br >, it works!  Firefox will not move the caret after a < br > if it's the last childNode.

Comment: You don't know how much I was struggling with this! Thank you very much! For people passing by, in javascript you can achieve this result with this little piece of code: 

divContainingTheTrailingBr.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));